# Location Required only in jar

Tags: java, javafx

I've been making a small java program to use and I am almost done with it. I tried exporting it as a runnable jar in both eclipse and IntelliJ but the jar is not running. I tried surrounding the launcher class in a try catch statement to see why and the exception.getMessage() simply says location required. I'm Using JavaFX for my GUI. Keep in mind that when I click run in both IDEs it runs perfectly.

I read a similar question here but it seemed that the person couldn't even run it in the IDE so please don't reference me back to it.

Note: I extracted the jar to see if my package containing my fxml file is in the jar and it is.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Use `e.printStackTrace()`, not `e.getMessage()`.

Comment: Where would that output if i ran the jar ?

Comment: found it using cmd thank you so much

Comment: Please show the exact error message that you see.

Comment: "I read a similar question..." You should post the link of this question yourself. That way we know which question to not refer you to.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Issue with mine was I was using relative path to get resources. For example

```
Parent addUser = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("../fxml/addUserGUI.fxml"));
```

I was using this, after changing it to

```
Parent addUser = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/BikeShop/fxml/addUserGUI.fxml"));
```

It worked. BikeShop is my package name here, is the root directory of the project.